# Strange behavior by RoundingMode.DOWN

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

Can someone explain the RoundingMode behavior seen in the examples to me? For the 2nd Example i would have expected 66.800 as a result not 66.799 .

**Example 1**:

```java
 BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal(66.7);
 bg1 = bg1.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

> Result: 66.700

**Example 2**:

```java
BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal(66.8);
bg1 = bg1.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

> Result: 66.799

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is that the `double` values you're providing aren't what you expect them to be. Use `new BigDecimal("66.7")` and `new BigDecimal("66.8")` instead.

Comment: The value of the `double` literal 66.7 is precisely 66.7000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125. The value of the `double` literal 66.8 is precisely 66.7999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875

Comment: In order to get `66.800` as a result you have to round up not down.

Comment: From [Javadocs for BigDecimal(double) constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-): "The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable (...) The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this one. "

Comment: the comments cleared my question. thank you all.